# Dataflow streaming pipeline error: "function 'get_message_id' is not defined". It works locally with DirectRunner but not on Dataflow

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, python-3.8, dataflow

I'm having a weird error when running an STREAMING pipeline in Dataflow.

I have tested the pipeline locally through DirectRunner and it works properly, but when I run it on Dataflow this happens:

[image]

[image]

Seems like it's not founding the get_message_id function, but it's actually there...

Any thoughts?

I have shorten the code just to focus on the relevant things here, but the entire workflow is much more bigger.

**EDIT:**

Any function or constant declared globally (outside the Classes) is not recognized by Dataflow. In this case, the function not recognized is evaluate_filter because it's executed in the first place. If I delete this function, the get_message_id function fails too.

I'm using:

- Python3.8
- Apache Beam 2.39.0
- Dataflow clasic template

I'm creating the template with this command through Cloud Shell

```
python3.8 -m ingestion_pipeline \
--runner DataflowRunner \
--project PROJECT_ID \
--staging_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/staging \
--temp_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/temp \
--template_location gs://BUCKET_NAME/templates/ingestion_pipeline \
--region europe-west1 \
--streaming
```

Code (Shortened):

```
import uuid
import json

from apache_beam import DoFn, GroupByKey, io, ParDo, Pipeline, PTransform, WindowInto, WithKeys
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1


# region *********************************  Declare constants  ********************************
BIGQUERY_SCHEMA = 'Publish_time:TIMESTAMP, Payload:STRING, Message_id: STRING'

# endregion *********************************  Declare constants  ************************************


# region *********************************  Input parameters  *********************************
class InputArguments(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        # ------------------- IN/OUT arguments -----------------------
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--output_table',
            dest='output_table',
            default='xxxxxxxxxxx',
            help='Output table',
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--output_schema',
            dest='output_schema',
            default=BIGQUERY_SCHEMA,
            help='Output BigQuery Schema in text format',
        )


# endregion *********************************  Input parameters  *********************************


# region *********************************  Aux functions  ************************************
def get_pubsub_topic():

    project_id = "XXXXXXXX"
    topic_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"

    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    # The `topic_path` method creates a fully qualified identifier
    # in the form `projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic_id}`
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)

    print(topic_path)

    return topic_path


def get_message_id(message_id):
    print('get_message_id function - start')
    message_id = uuid.uuid4() if message_id == '' else message_id
    print('get_message_id function - end')
    return str(message_id)


def evaluate_filter():

    print('evaluate_filter function - start')

    print('evaluate_filter function - end')
    return True

# endregion *********************************  Aux functions  ************************************

# region *********************************  PCollections  *************************************


class CustomParsing(DoFn):
    """
        Parse messages to store the payload in BigQuery.
    """
    def process(self, element):
        """
        Simple processing function to parse the data and add a timestamp
        For additional params see:
        https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.7.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html#apache_beam.transforms.core.DoFn
        """

        print('CustomParsing PCollection - start')

        payload = element.data.decode("utf-8")
        publish_time = element.publish_time.timestamp()
        
        evaluate_filter = evaluate_filter()

    
        message_id = get_message_id(element.message_id)

        data_set = {
            'Payload': payload,
            'Publish_time': publish_time,
            'Message_id': message_id
        }

        json_dump = json.dumps(data_set)
        json_data = json.loads(json_dump)

        print('CustomParsing PCollection - end')
        yield json_data


# endregion *********************************  PCollections  **********************************

def run(save_main_session=True):
    """
    Build and run Pipeline
    """
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
        streaming=True
    )
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session

    pubsub_topic = get_pubsub_topic()

    # --------------------------- Run pipeline ----------------------------------
    with Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        input_args = pipeline_options.view_as(InputArguments)
        rows = (pipeline | 'Read from Pub/Sub' >> io.ReadFromPubSub(pubsub_topic, with_attributes=True))

        write_bq = (
                rows
                | 'Parse messages' >> ParDo(CustomParsing())
                | "Write to BigQuery" >> io.WriteToBigQuery(input_args.output_table,
                                                            input_args.output_schema,
                                                            write_disposition=io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: Can you include the part of the code that uses `get_message_id`?

Comment: @KennKnowles it's there, inside the CustomParsing class.

Comment: the simplest way to fix this would be to define `get_message_id` as a static function inside `CustomParsing` is this something you would be willing to do?

Comment: Oh ha I failed to scroll

Comment: @Pablo this is not the case, but what if I need to use the function in multiple ParDo functions? Feels like losing recursion...

Comment: right. If you need this to be part of other functions, then you may need to pass an argument : --pickle_main_session - or you can define it in a separate file that you import for your pipeline.

Comment: @Pablo when I try to add this I have the following error: WARNING:apache_beam.options.pipeline_options:Discarding unparseable args: ['--pickle_main_session']

Answer (score 3):

This works for my dataflow pipeline:

Put the external method and the custom DoFn into separate files and import the former into the latter. Next, import the DoFn into your main file and use a setup.py ([described here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#multiple-file-dependencies)) for the deployment of dataflow.

Don't forget to put an empty `__init__.py` within your `other_files_dir/`

Comment: does it require to create a flex template? I would like to use Classic one.

Comment: I'm using a classic template as well, and as far as I know (thought that I have not tested) it should also work without any template at all.

Comment: I though setup.py only works with flex templates... i will take a look

Comment: Okay mate, this works! U get the bounty. Thank you so much!

Comment: Absolute hero! Don't know why this isn't talked about in the docs.