# NameError: name 'func' is not defined [while running 'Map(<lambda at testing.py:273>)-ptransform-38']

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am working with Apache Beam and ProtoBuf on Google Dataflow.

```
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        data = (
            p
            | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription='projects/abc/subscriptions/abc-sub')
            | beam.Map(lambda x: convert_proto_to_dict(x, protobuf_schema_pb2.Message))
        )
```

This was my Apache Beam call convert_proto_to_dict func.

The function code is as follows (which I don't think should matter):

```
def convert_proto_to_dict(data, schema_class):
    from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToDict

    message = schema_class()
    message.ParseFromString(data)   
    return MessageToDict(message, preserving_proto_field_name=True)
```

I get the following traceback:

> NameError: name 'convert_proto_to_dict' is not defined [while running 'Map(<lambda at testing.py:273>)-ptransform-38']

I research the way to fix this problem, some recommended using `beam.Map(convert_proto_to_dict, protobuf_schema_pb2.Message` stead of `beam.Map(lambda x: convert_proto_to_dict(x, protobuf_schema_pb2.Message))`. But this way beam will use **DoFn** and **DoFn** can not work with protobuf(I don't know why).
I am not sure what I am missing. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Make sure you aren't calling the function convert_proto_to_dict before defining it.

Comment: Where do you define your function `convert_proto_to_dict`? Is it all located within `main.py` or are you using another file? This post might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72614323/dataflow-streaming-pipeline-error-function-get-message-id-is-not-defined-i

Comment: I found the error, it happens when I add other functions in main, but I never used it. Then the pipeline showed this error. I don't know why, it's so weird :)))

Answer (score 0):

Does running the pipeline locally with a DirectRunner work? If so, it should be a FAQ [NameError](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#how_do_i_handle_nameerrors). You can try setting `--save_main_session` pipeline option to True.

Comment: I added `--save_main_session` pipeline option to True, but this error happened when I add other functions in main, but I never used it. I don't know why.

Comment: Could you please update your OP with a minimum script that reproduces this issue?