# NameError when running Apache Beam pipeline on Google Dataflow when using nested functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am working on an Apache Beam pipeline in Python, and I'm encountering a NameError when running the pipeline on Google Dataflow. The error specifically mentions that 'json_encoder' is not defined. The pipeline works fine when running it locally.

Here's the gist of the code:

```
import apache_beam as beam
import decimal

# Simplified Apache Beam pipeline step
input | "Convert to string" >> beam.Map(encode_as_task)

def encode_as_task(element, cache_enabled=False):
    import orjson
    # Convert the element to a string before publishing to Pub/Sub
    task = dict()
    tasks = []
    task['task'] = element[2][0]
    task['task'].pop('client_id', None)
    task['clientIds'] = element[1]
    tasks.append(task)
    task_generator_request = {"tasks": tasks, "cacheEnabled": cache_enabled}
    message = orjson.dumps(task_generator_request, default=json_encoder)
    return message

def json_encoder(value):
    if isinstance(value, decimal.Decimal):
        return float(value)
    raise TypeError
```

This code works well locally.

But when running in cloud dataflow I get the following error. `NameError: name 'json_encoder' is not defined.`

I used to get these issues when dealing with external dependencies such as orjson.
I resolved those by importing the package inside the function directly like `import orjson` in `encode_as_task`.

But since `json_encoder` is an internal function, not sure how to handle or import the same.

Side note, I am sending the requirement file using beam runtime argument,  `--requirements_file=requirements.txt` to tell apache beam and dataflow regarding the dependencies. Still facing these issues.

Comment: If you eventually want to outsource your code to different files, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72631160/16622985) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you pass --save_main_session to the pipeline options?  Saving main session means it saves the funcs and variables in the **main** class so they can pickled and unpickled on the Dataflow.

For more info on save_main_session, please take a look at https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.51.0/_modules/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.html